# Provide jquery explcitly with requirejs

Tags: requirejs

I'm working on a page that is in progress of transitioning from script tags to require.js. This means that some dependencies are loaded via `<script>` and others via require.

For the most part, in my require modules I can still treat global scripts as modoules (and thereby help the transition) by doing something like this in my bootstrapping file

```
define('Globalize', Globalize);
define('knockout', ko);
```

However this won't work with jQuery since it is a function and require will try to invoke it as a callback. Is there a way to tell require *"yes this is a function but return it directly, don't try to invoke it"*?

And yeah, I can't just load jquery twice because I've got bootstrap modifying it, and things depending on bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh...

```
define('jquery', function() { return window.jQuery});
```

duh.